# Controller Action not found missing required key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I believe my error is its missing the specific tea id to render the tea review page. But I am not sure if I am reading this error correctly. Below is the error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"reviews"}, missing required keys: [:tea_id]

1 <h1> All Tea Blends </h1>
2
3
4 <% @teas.each do |tea| %>
5
6 <h2><%= link_to tea.flavor, tea_path(tea.id)%> - <%= tea.brand.name %> </h2>
7 <% link_to "Write a review", new_tea_review_path%>
```

Comment: It should be `new_tea_review_path(tea)`.

Answer (score 0):

The route path will be linking to your new action in your controller. By default rails makes a private method which will set the tea object for you.

Therefore the action that you are looking for is `new_tea_review_path(tea)` since it is being fed to the view by the controller. You can see this in line 4 where you are looping through each tea. The `@teas` variable is provided by your tea controller.